# different results compiling gcc and clang

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Can someone explain me, why compiling this piece of code have different behavior. For example `gcc` have infinite loop, but `clang` works as expected.

Yeap, I know that code more than ugly, it was wrote by me couple years ago, just wondering why switching machine have such impact on such an easy code, at least I didn't use stack, heap, pointers, nothing at all.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int a,b,state,nl,i,temp1,temp2;
    int words[10];
    nl = temp1 = 0;
    for( i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ )
        words[i] = 0; 
    while((a = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        nl++;   
        if( a == ' ' || a == '\t' || a == '\n' )
        {
            words[nl-2]++;
            nl = 0;
        }
    }
    for(b=0; b < 10; b++)
        printf("%d",words[b]);
    printf("\n");
    for( b = 1 ; b <= 10 ; b++)
        printf("%d",b);
    printf("\n");
    for( b = 0 ; b <= 10 ; b++)
        if(words[b]>temp1)
            temp1=words[b];
    //printf("%d\n", temp1);
    for(; temp1 > 0 ; temp1--)
    {
        for(i= 0 ; i <= 10 ; ++i)
        {   
            if(words[i]>0)
            {
                //  temp2 = i;
                //  for(; temp2 > 0; temp2--)
                //  printf(" ");
                printf("#");
                words[i]--;
            }
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What input are you providing to this code?

Comment: @AndrewL. spiffing an `int` won't change anything, so your comment out of scope of this problem. Be more precise please, I already told that code is literally bad.

Comment: @BillLynch `./a.out < source.c` should print histogram of word length

Answer (score 4):

At the very least:

- `words[nl-2]++;` could be called when `nl == 1` which would cause undefined behavior.
- `temp1=words[b];` can be called when `b == 10` which is accessing an array out of bounds.
- `if(words[b]>temp1)` will be called when `b == 10`, which is accessing an array out of bounds.
- `if(words[i]>0)` will be called when `i == 10`, which is accessing an array out of bounds.
- `words[i]--;` could be called when `i == 10`, which is accessing an array out of bounds.

In general, different compilers will fall over differently when given undefined behavior.

Comment: So correct me if I wrong: `clang` is more tolerant to process fail code than `gcc`, which means that `gcc` more safety, in case `clang` can produce code that leads to undefined behavior ?

Comment: @kAldown: They merely fail differently. I wouldn't trust this code in any compiler.